# PHP LDAPS unable to connect to server

Tags: php, ldap, cloud

```
          $username = $_POST['username'];
          $password = $_POST['password'];

         $ldaphost = "ldaps://corpldap.xxx.net";
         $ldapUsername = "cn=$username,ou=people,dc=xxx,dc=net";
         $ldapPassword = "$password";


       $ds = ldap_connect($ldaphost,636) or die("\r\nCould not connect to LDAP server\r\n");
  echo $ds; //this output 'Resource id #21'
       ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

   if (!ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3)) {
print "Could not set LDAPv3\r\n";
} else {
 // now we need to bind to the ldap server
echo 'success'; //echo success output 
  $bth = ldap_bind($ds) or die("\r\nCould not connect to LDAP server\r\n");
 }
```

I get 'Resource id #21 success 
Could not connect to LDAP server'

so ldap_bind is failing

stack trace on error log: 
PHP Warning:  ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server

How can i fix this? Please help.

Please note: i also tried   $ldaphost = "ldaps://corpldap.xxx.net:636";

I also tried echoing php_info() which shows ldap enabled.

Comment: `$ldaphost` is a HOSTNAME, not a url. it should be just `corpldap.xxx.net`.

Comment: so it has to be $ldaphost ="corpldap.xxx.net:636" ?

Comment: actually, never mind. it has to be a url for the secure version. apologies...

Comment: More than likely the certificate is not trusted from where you're running your code. You could add `ldap_set_option(null, LDAP_OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 7);` before the `ldap_connect()` and it should give you all the details you need. Are you using PHP on Linux or Windows?

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot! i have more details in error.log!   Looking at this ldap_init: trying c:\openldap\sysconf\ldap.conf
ldap_init: HOME env is NULL
ldap_init: trying ldaprc    I can see no folder openldap under C:/( and i dont have privileges to create one) 
But i have a openldap/sysconf folder  C:\xampp-win32-5.6.21-0-VC11\xampp\licenses\openldap\sysconf                                                            so my question is how do i point to this one instead of c:/openldap?

Comment: Forgot to mention php on windows